# Nodemailer SES TRANSPORT Error: TypeError: this.ses.sendRawEmail is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, nodemailer, amazon-ses

I am trying to configure AWS SES with the help of nodemailer.
So I am following the [documentation](https://nodemailer.com/transports/ses/).
This is the code that they provided and that I tested:

```
let nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
let aws = require("@aws-sdk/client-ses");

const ses = new aws.SES({
  apiVersion: "2010-12-01",
  region: "us-west-2",
});

// create Nodemailer SES transporter
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  SES: { ses, aws },
});

// send some mail
transporter.sendMail(
  {
    // These are obviously not the actual emails I am using
    from: "configured_aws_email",
    to: "recipient_email",
    subject: "Message",
    text: "I hope this message gets sent!",
    ses: {
      // optional extra arguments for SendRawEmail
      Tags: [
        {
          Name: "tag_name",
          Value: "tag_value",
        },
      ],
    },
  },
  (err, info) => {
    console.log(
      " ~ file: transactional-email-confiig.js ~ line 36 ~ err",
      err
    );
    console.log(
      " ~ file: transactional-email-confiig.js ~ line 41 ~ info.envelope",
      info.envelope
    );
    console.log(
      " ~ file: transactional-email-confiig.js ~ line 43 ~ info.messageId",
      info.messageId
    );
  }
);
```

These are the versions of the required packaged I installed:

> package.json

```
"@aws-sdk/client-ses": "^3.40.0",
"aws-sdk": "^2.1026.0",
```

I configured the AWS keys in the .env file:

> .env

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=***************
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*************
```

This is the node version:

> node -v

```
v15.8.0
```

And the AWS SES email address I am using is verified:
[image]

But, I keep getting this error:

```
node_modules/nodemailer/lib/ses-transport/index.js:242
                this.ses.sendRawEmail(sesMessage, (err, data) => {
                         ^

TypeError: this.ses.sendRawEmail is not a function
```

Answer (score 2):

For those using `import` instead of `require`, check that you use this:

```
`import aws from '@aws-sdk/client-ses';`
`import * as aws from '@aws-sdk/client-ses';`
```

as stated [here](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1293#issuecomment-878031206).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `@aws-sdk/client-ses` interface doesn't have `sendRawEmail` method.

Try to install the older `aws-sdk` package:

`npm i aws-sdk`

And use it instead

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const aws = require("aws-sdk");

const ses = new aws.SES({
  apiVersion: "2010-12-01",
  region: "us-west-2",
});

// create Nodemailer SES transporter
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  SES: { ses, aws },
});
```

Comment: `aws-sdk` is v2 while v3 is all modular. `@aws-sdk/client-ses` The new function in v3 is called `SendRawEmailCommand`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility I ran into is jest mocking and refactoring, I was making a change from `sendEmail` to `sendRawEmail` and needed to update that mock declaration as well.